# Do I get points also when my edits are approved?

Tags: support

Looking at [my reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3598/kiamlaluno?tab=reputation), I noticed that I received two points for a question that has not been asked by me, and to which I didn't answer. The only thing I did was to suggest an edit, and that edit has been [approved](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/8426/revisions).

Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested edit feature is fairly new.

From the [FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation-gain):

> The other way to gain reputation is by suggesting edits to existing posts as a new registered user. Each edit will be peer reviewed, and if it is accepted, you will earn +2 reputation. You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however.

There is also a [detailed MSO answer about suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284).

Comment: Thank you. I clearly missed that part.